# How to underline each component? React + CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, computer-science

Hi I am having trouble working with the css for my component. I created a joke component which has a joke and punchline props. The problem is that when it appears on the compiler my joke component which i call twice only appears as text. I want to know how I can style these components in css and be able to change it so that each  has an underline at the bottom of the joke so it separates each joke from another.

Can someone help me with the CSS required for this? Thank you

```js
import React from "react"
import Joke from "./Joke"


function App() {
return (
<div>
<Joke
jokes="how much gum is enough"
punchline="yes"
/>

<Joke
jokes="are you tall"
punchline="yes"
/>

</div>
)
}




export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add inline style to the div:

```
   <div style={{"text-decoration": "underline"}}>
```